# Effects of hypophosphatemia on DNA

Tags: endocrinology, dna

There is a lot of supportive evidence that its role in ATP results in much of the clinical manifestation of hypophosphatemia, but I was wondering about the other roles where Phosphate is an important part of nucleic acids in DNA, and RNA so what happens to these in hypophosphatemia?

How is cell membrane or critical component of cell signaling (phospyrlation or component of cAMP affected?)

Comment: Good question, but it may receive a faster answer in Biology.SE - and would be on topic there, since it's a general biochem/physiology topic.